# How can this three dimensional ball maze be solved?

Tags: mazes

[image]You have to manually move the ball around; holes join sides and front-and-back, and as far I can tell you get blocked in the back.
[image]

[image: Top and back with one side (stock image)][image: Side from Start]
[image: Bottom- Top of this is from Start of Top (some variation from stock image]
[image: Side Top from Start side of Top]
[image: Side Right side joins left of Start]
[![Side Left side joins Right of Start][7]][7]

My son is trying solve it, and I want to make sure it can be solved from スタート(start)　to ゴール(goal)。

Note the edges of the sides all have two holes on each left and right that join the other sides.

[image]

Hat tip to Graylocke for basically providing the maze diagram which I cleaned up and corrected.

Comment: The photos are not very clear (to me), especially: The top right and third photo seem to be the same, except that the top right hat 3 exists at the far side, and the 3rd only 2. Can you explain why?

Comment: The third photo and top right are the same thing but the top one is some else's professional photo but  obscures the side view. Sorry these are best photos I could take with my Kindle 8 HD.

Comment: The solution path seems to go around a corner between the sides, so photos from the four diagonal angles would be helpful. You get sharper images by lighting the scene a bit more. (Also, these photos are focused on the keyboard in the background, you can probably tap the screen to select a focus point on the puzzle.)

Comment: One thing to note, I am not sure if it is necessary to solve the maze but there seems to be a notch missing on the back side of your maze compared to the professional photo ones. (notice on their photos the back side has 4, 3, 2, 4 exits to the side of the box but yours seems to have 2, 2, 4, 4)

Comment: I also think the second photo (first taken by you) and the last photo show the same side, so you've only shown 3 of 4 smaller sides.

Comment: I actually have a similar puzzle several years ago and it's solvable. But yes need to recheck, maybe the layout for this one is different.

Comment: I am really surprised by the quality of the photos ...

Comment: You should be able to use the "left-hand on the wall" or "right-hand on the wall" technique (both should work). Imagine that you are the ball and take every left turn you can as you move through. There will be some deadends, but you will simply go in and out and then turn left again. It looks like it will work because the start and end are connected

Comment: I thought I had solved it once after posting but I couldn't back track.

Comment: Awesome - Glad the pic helped!  I am also glad someone helped solve it for you! :)

Comment: Nitpick: in the orange diagram, directly above W3, there seems to be a hole that should not be a hole.

Comment: It looks a half-thickness wall as the hole abuts to a wall but I fixed it for consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It can be solved.  Using the corrected maze diagram provided by @Graylocke, I believe a possible solution would be:

> [image]
>  You can follow the colors using the legend at the bottom to quickly find the path.

Comment: Awesome! :)  Glad it was solvable.

Comment: @Graylocke I'm curious... Which application did you use to create the diagram?

Comment: All I did was use a spreadsheet!  My usual process for mazes and other "pencil-and-paper" type puzzles is to replicate grids by simply sizing the height and width of cells.  In this case, I just clicked and set borders.  If you are truly nerdy you might recognise the default MS Office colour palettes I used for the bgs and walls ;p

Comment: That's awesome!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if I have copied everything correctly... however:

> [image]

As a guide:

> The blue area I got from Image 3
>  The orange area I got from Image 2
>  The green area I got from Image 5
>  The yellow area I got from Image 6
>  The dark grey area I got from Image 7
>  I had to interpret the light grey area from Image 1 and what I had already.

I am really curious as to whether my interpretation of the photos is correct because:

> the answer seems not to require more than the top and one edge? Not to mention that there is more than one way to leave start and get to the gate I have marked E1.

**EDIT (Post Solve by Kyle Williamson**
Just as a side note, there are many ways of solving mazes (wall-hugging etc) though I find that I get lost if I try to tackle the whole of a "wrapping" maze such as this one.

Not that you have asked for one, but my mechanism for solving this kind of maze would be:

0. (If you don't have it - Draw a map!)
1. Label all of your "transfer points" on each map piece uniquely using the same marker on both sides.
2. Start at the Exit and list all the transfer points that you could reach without going through one.
3. Cross off any that lead to a dead end
4. If they aren't a dead end, list the new transfer points you can get to from this point *that aren't earlier in your chain*.
5. Continue until one transfer point is Start.

Not the most elegant process, but it works.

Comment: Your transcription is not quite correct so the answer is wrong. Can I get a copy and correct it  and include it in the question?

Comment: Note that the "right-hand on the wall" technique I mentioned in my comment to the OP gets something quite similar to your solution (with a few extra deadends). The "left-hand on the wall" gives another different but it also works.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can send it to you easier than you using the image that is linked?

Comment: The image is not linked. I have been trying to clean it up the pasted image but not getting a good result. You haven't given me specific permission to use the image- some sites get thingy about that.

Comment: @Graylocke Your mechanism for solving the puzzle was exactly what I did!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative- maybe a bit better because it avoids one face of the cuboid. It is very challenging controlling the ball going around the maze and you want to make it as simple as possible.

> [image]